# Making AJAX show a 'result data' in correct div witoud refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, vote

I'm currently into developing simple 'one score' votting system and I'm facing the problem: though php script workd fine I cant get AJAX updating the answer div without reloading page. I've tried different methods, some do nothing, other reload page, for example, I've tried adding (return: false) after AJAX or PreventDefault in it. Here is html and php index page:

```
<body>
<div align="center">
<h3>Voting with jQuery, Ajax and PHP</h3>
<?php
include('config.php');
$sql=mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT * FROM messages  LIMIT 9");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
$msg=$row['msg'];
$mes_id=$row['mes_id'];
$total_score=$row['total_score'];
?>
<div id="main">
<div class="box1">
<a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="up"><img        class='image'src="img/thumbsup.png"></a> 
<span class='this'><?php echo $total_score; ?></span><div class='tr'></div>
<a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="down"><img    class='image' src="img/icon-down.png"></a></div>
<div class='box2' ><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
```

And here is my working up_vote.php (down_vote.php is almost same, so I wont add it)

```
<?php
 include("config.php");
 $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
$ip_sql=mysqli_query($bd,"select ip_add from Voting_IP where mes_id_fk='$id' and   ip_add='$ip'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($ip_sql);
$sql = "update Messages set total_score=total_score+1  where mes_id='$id'";
mysqli_query($bd, $sql);
$sql_in = "insert into Messages (mes_id_fk,ip_add) values ('$id','$ip')";
mysqli_query($bd, $sql_in);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($ip_sql);
}
?>
```

And finally, the complete JQUERY - AJAX script (this's my problem - need to show the results in (div class = 'this') without refreshing the page):

```
$(function() {
$(".vote").click(function() 
{
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var parent = $(this);
if(name=='up')
{ 
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "up_vote.php",
 data: dataString,
 cache: false,
 success:function(data){    
 $(".this").append(data);
 },
 complete: function() {alert('complete');}; 

});} else
{
$(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="img/icon-down.png" align="absmiddle"   style="height: 10px;width:10px;">');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "down_vote.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false
}).done(function ( data ) {
$('.this').append(data);
});
} 
return false;
});
});
```

I have spent whole my day and I know the solution is obvious, Im just really new in this all and so I would appreciate any helpful response. Thanks in advance.

**I have added this code to up_vote.php at the buttom:**

```
$result=mysqli_query($bd, "select total_score from Messages where  mes_id='$id'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$up_value=$row['total_score'];
echo $up_value;
```

***Thanks to all of you guyz!!! It works now! The problem was that php script didnt return anything!!! As I though - obviouse))) THANKS!***

HAve NEW PROBLEM NOW - WHEN I CLICK ON ICONS IT UPDATES ALL OF THEM!! IN EVERY DIV! I VOTE FOR ONE THING - AND IT ADDS VOTES FOR EACH ONE!! whats wrong with that?

Comment: Your php up_vote.php does not return anything

Comment: Try doing echo $count=mysqli_num_rows($ip_sql);

Comment: $result=mysqli_query($bd, "select total_score from Messages where mes_id='$id'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$up_value=$row['total_score'];
echo $up_value; - if i add this in up_vote.php should it work?

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working.

Comment: Try to make an alert data in your succes function.

Comment: Change `data: dataString,` to `data: { id: id},`

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Thanks a lot - one problem was in php script that echoed nothing!